# Wrapping Ruby global variables within a scope

Tags: ruby, scope, closures

I'm evaluating scripts in Ruby, and I'd like each script to have it's own sandbox with a global variable called `$window`. The `$window` variable should point to something different depending on which sandbox the script is running in. A thread-local variable would work, but I'm not using threads. I'm using the Ruby C API, so that opens the possibilities a bit.

Right now, I run each script within a `Binding`, so they are somewhat sandboxed there. A binding can have closed local variables, but not globals. Here's the idea:

```
sandbox1 = window1.get_binding
sandbox2 = window2.get_binding
sandbox3 = window3.get_binding

sandbox1.eval('$window.foo') # calls 'foo' on window 1
sandbox2.eval('$window.foo') # calls 'foo' on window 2
sandbox3.eval('$window.foo') # calls 'foo' on window 3
```

Is there any way to close a global variable within a `Binding`? I found a possible solution and posted it below.

Comment: It sounds like you're worried about synchronizing the access of several threads to a global?

Comment: They're not in separate threads, although that would make it easy! They're different windows in a web browser.

Comment: What is the underlying goal you are trying to accomplish? Global variables are generally considered a bad practice.

Comment: I clarified my question. I want to have multiple sandboxes with global variables of the same name.

Comment: Why was this tagged `javascript` and `webkit`?

Comment: Before the edit, I mentioned that the purpose is to duplicate the functionality of the `window` global variable in JavaScript. Also, the implementation would be for WebKit. Sorry, I forgot to remove the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution using the Ruby C API. Anything that's evaluated within a binding will be somewhere under the call frame of that binding. Using Ruby 1.8.7, I can do this in C:

```
public VALUE getCurrentWindow()
{
    // Get the current call frame from Ruby.
    FRAME* frame = ruby_frame;

    // Traverse up the call frame stack until we find a Window class.
    while (frame) {
        if (RTEST(rb_obj_is_kind_of(frame->self, rb_cWindow))
            return frame->self;

        frame = frame->prev;
    }

    // Couldn't find the window.
    return Qnil;
}
```

It seems to work, but we'll see if I run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

What will be the different windows be tied to ?

If they're bound to a Thread, then the easiest way to solve your problem is to have a [Thread local variable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-5B-5D), if is bound to something else (let's say current time), then you might want to use a global hash.

I would personnally go for a dedicated class which will make it easier to refactor later (you will probably refactor this since globals are a code smell for poor dependency injection ) :

```
class Windows < Hash
end
WINDOWS = Windows.new
...
window_scope = WINDOWS[Time.now].binding
```

then you have a mutable constant which is actually a global collection.

Comment: Sadly, they're not bound to threads, but using a global hash of some sort might work. I'll edit the main post with some clarification.